# rspec expect symbol not equal to created object

Tags: ruby, rspec

I wrote a test for controll with rspec:

```
it "populates an array of books" do
  book = FactoryGirl.create(:book)
  get :index
  expect(:books).to eql([book])
end
```

books_controller.rb

```
def index
  @books = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")   
end
```

books.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :book do |f|
    f.name { Faker::Book.title }
    f.author { Faker::Book.author }
    f.press { Faker::Book.publisher }
    f.cover { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'photos', 'testcover.jpg'), 'image/png') }
  end
end
```

Run bin/rake spec, the result is:

```
1) BooksController GET #index populates an array of books
 Failure/Error: expect(:books).to eql([book])

   expected: [#<Book id: 1, name: "The Waste Land", author: "谢靖琪", isbn: nil, press: "University of Chicago Press"...e: "image/png", cover_file_size: 104531, cover_updated_at: "2016-08-26 04:00:19", page_number: nil>]
        got: :books

   (compared using eql?)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -[#<Book id: 1, name: "The Waste Land", author: "谢靖琪", isbn: nil, press: "University of Chicago Press", description: nil, grade_level: nil, lexile_level: nil, douban_link: nil, scholastic_link: nil, created_at: "2016-08-26 04:00:19", updated_at: "2016-08-26 04:00:19", cover_file_name: "fcbcb7417dbc88827d16765a.jpg", cover_content_type: "image/png", cover_file_size: 104531, cover_updated_at: "2016-08-26 04:00:19", page_number: nil>]
   +:books
```

They are not equal. It seems that the first expected result, '...' is an abbreviation. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why's `:symbol` books should equal an object `book`? I can't get what you want.

Comment: I want to test the index method, there are "@books = Book.all" in books_controller#index.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is

```
expect(assigns(:books)).to eq([book])
```

Comment: Yes, it's my fault. Thanks.

Comment: If helped you, chose the answer as the right one, so other users now which answer you chose. =)